# Realtime ETW with TX

Tags: c#, system.reactive, etw

I've been working with ETW via the Trace Event Library for some time and I'm now looking at the TX library.

However despite reading the docs and downloading the samples I'm struggling to get started. All the ETW examples seem to revolve around reading etl files which is not what I am trying to do. I can't find an example for starting a session and getting the data.

For example the LINQPad code starts a sessions a subscribes to a specific event (Process Freeze) using the Trace Event Library

```
var sessionName = "My ETW Session";
var providerName = "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process";
using (var session = new TraceEventSession(sessionName))
{
    session.EnableProvider(providerName, TraceEventLevel.Verbose, 0x00000200);
    var parser = new RegisteredTraceEventParser(session.Source);

    parser
        .Observe(providerName, "ProcessFreeze/Start")
        .Select(te => new
        {
            ProcessID = te.ProcessID,
            FrozenProcessID = te.PayloadByName("FrozenProcessID"),
            CreateTime = te.PayloadByName("CreateTime"),
            ThreadID = te.ThreadID,
            te.TimeStamp,
            Raw = te.ToString(),                
        })
        .DumpLatest();

    session.Source.Process();
}
```

How can a do the equivalent in TX?
Do I need to extract the manifest for `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process` and use that to generate the classes?
How do I start a session with the required options and subscribe to it?

Edit:
I've had some success getting some data back by subscribing to the session just created with this

```
var etwTraceSessionObservable = EtwObservable.FromSession(sessionName);
etwTraceSessionObservable.DumpLatest();
```

Although it doesn't contain much useful data. I think I want to be using AddRealTimeSession to a playback object.

Comment: Can you please describe what's going wrong with your existing code?

Comment: The code with Trace Event Library library works fine, but we have a lot of issues with the library (memory leaks, very hard to unit test, Observe clones everything).